# FB GRAPH API - Not able to get group posts all details

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I want to access the posted post all detail in my group wall using FB API 3.2. I can get only the post Title, posted date, ID but when some post the Youtube/vimeo video to post (eg. http://prntscr.com/ly6td8) then that video Title, Link, Post comment etc is not access. I have try using API but its always return just post title and ID, not attached video details so let me know how to get that info using API?

I Have used this API Call to get Group post list:

```
$response = $fb->get('/MY GROUUP ID','MY ACCESS TOKEN');
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

So Any buddy help me to get all info of Group's Post detail?

Comment: you need to include the relevant code too, this is too broad for stackoverflow right now. we are developers, don´t be shy with details ;)

Comment: I have Added the code above And we need the song title, URL and other meta-data of any Youtube/Vimeo videos posted onto the group.

Comment: you are not even asking for those things, so of course you don´t get any other data. please check out the basic graph api tutorials in the official docs.